# Modifing A Static Variable Based On The Value Of A Different Variable (Coding A MC Hacked Client)

Tags: java

I Am Coding Something For Minecraft...And Am Trying To Change The Location Of Certain Text Based Off The GUI Scale...My Question Relates To Changing The X Position For The Text Based Off The Games Gui Scale...My Code Is:

```
public int scale = Wrapper.mc.gameSettings.guiScale;
public static int XScale = 865;{
if(scale == 0 ){
        int XScale = 405;
    }else if(scale == 1 ){
        int XScale = 1835;
    }else if(scale == 2){
        int XScale = 865;
    }else if(scale == 3){
        int XScale = 565;
    }
}
```

My Issue Is That No Matter What My GUI Scale Is, The XScale Variable Doesn't Seem To Change, And It Needs to Be Static Because When It's Not Static The Individual Things Being Rendered Want It To Be Static...So I Make Them Not Static...And Then The Render Class Wants Them To Be Static...Get The Idea?

---EDIT---
I Have Tried What @AntonH Said, To No Avail...The Outcome Hasn't Changed...Should I Put It Inside A Loop? The New Code Is:

```
public int scale = Wrapper.mc.gameSettings.guiScale;
public static int XScale = 865;{
if(scale == 0 ){
        GUIIngameHook.XScale = 405;
    }else if(scale == 1 ){
        GUIIngameHook.XScale = 1835;
    }else if(scale == 2){
        GUIIngameHook.XScale = 865;
    }else if(scale == 3){
        GUIIngameHook.XScale = 565;
    }
}
```

---ENTIRE SCRIPT---
Not Sure How Helpful This Will Be...But It Should Provide Context..

```
package me.zach.frostwave.UI;

public class GUIIngameHook {
public static void StartHud(){
    renderClientName();
    renderCoords();
    renderFPS();
    renderMods();
    renderArrayList();
    renderModLine();
}
public int scale = Wrapper.mc.gameSettings.guiScale;
public static int XScale = 865;{
if(scale == 0 ){
        GUIIngameHook.XScale = 405;
    }else if(scale == 1 ){
        GUIIngameHook.XScale = 1835;
    }else if(scale == 2){
        GUIIngameHook.XScale = 865;
    }else if(scale == 3){
        GUIIngameHook.XScale = 565;
    }
}


public static void renderClientName() {
    Wrapper.fr.drawString("Frost Wave [MCV: 1.10, V: 0.05A]", 5, 5,  0x0011FF);
    FrostWave.Frostwave.getGuiManager().renderPinned();
    FrostWave.Frostwave.getGuiManager().update();
}

public static void renderFPS() {
    Wrapper.fr.drawStringWithShadow("[FPS:" + Wrapper.mc.getDebugFPS() + "]", 5, 15,   0x7AA7FF);
    FrostWave.Frostwave.getGuiManager().renderPinned();
    FrostWave.Frostwave.getGuiManager().update();
}

public static void renderCoords() {
    Wrapper.fr.drawStringWithShadow("[Coords: X: " + (int) Wrapper.mc.thePlayer.posX + " Y: " + (int) Wrapper.mc.thePlayer.posY + " Z: " + (int) Wrapper.mc.thePlayer.posZ + "]" , 5, 25, 0x10F0DA);
    FrostWave.Frostwave.getGuiManager().renderPinned();
    FrostWave.Frostwave.getGuiManager().update();
}
public static void renderMods() {
    Wrapper.fr.drawString(" [Active Mods]" , XScale, 5, 0x5A47FF);
    FrostWave.Frostwave.getGuiManager().renderPinned();
    FrostWave.Frostwave.getGuiManager().update();
}
public static void renderModLine() {
    Wrapper.fr.drawString("-------------" , XScale, 11, 0x5A47FF);
    FrostWave.Frostwave.getGuiManager().renderPinned();
    FrostWave.Frostwave.getGuiManager().update();
}

public static void renderArrayList() {
    int yCount = 17;
    for(Module m : FrostWave.manager.activeModules){
        m.onRender();

        if(m.getState() && !m.isCategory(Category.GUI)){
            Wrapper.fr.drawString(m.getName(), XScale, yCount, m.getColor());
            yCount = yCount + 10;
        }
    }
} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it

```
public static int XScale = 865;{
if(scale == 0 ){
        int XScale = 405;
    }else if(scale == 1 ){
        int XScale = 1835;
    }else if(scale == 2){
        int XScale = 865;
    }else if(scale == 3){
        int XScale = 565;
    }
}
```

Should be

```
public static int XScale = 865;

static {
    switch (scale) {
    case 0:
        XScale = 405;
        break;
    case 1:
        XScale = 1835;
        break;
    case 3:
        XScale = 565;
        break;
    }
}
```

Use a `static` block.

Comment: alright, I will give this a shot...this code will take a static variable as its modifier, and then takes the GUI scale as its base code and depending on its value will run something different...so it's like a fancy if statement?

Comment: when putting that in, it wants me to change the scale variable into a static...will this stop the scale variable from being changed as well?

Comment: A `switch` statement is a way to execute a block of code based on the value of some variable. So, yes, it is like a fancy `if`. It's much more restricted than an `if`, but it's easier to read in this case.

Comment: Everything inside a `static` block has to be static. making something static does not make it unchangeable. The `final` operator makes things unchangeable.

Comment: is their an easy way to make it check every second?

Comment: I am pretty sure the API you are using has a way to inform you when the screen changes its scale, but I do not know this API so I can't tell you how. Well, if my answer worked, give it the accepted mark.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change first code from this:

```
if(scale == 0 ){
    int XScale = 405;
}else if(scale == 1 ){
    int XScale = 1835;
}else if(scale == 2){
    int XScale = 865;
}else if(scale == 3){
    int XScale = 565;
}
```

to that:

```
if(scale == 0 ){
    XScale = 405;
}else if(scale == 1 ){
    XScale = 1835;
}else if(scale == 2){
    XScale = 865;
}else if(scale == 3){
    XScale = 565;
}
```

Comment: It appears not to work...would you like me to make a video showing what it actually does?

Comment: Even not solving your problem entirely, this answer solves a obvious problem in your code. You are creating a new variable called `XScale` instead of assigning a value to the outer `XScale`.

Comment: so what I was doing originally was creating a new variable? now it attempts to change the current one?

Comment: Exactly. When you put a type before an identifier, you are declaring it.